# Como fazer esse tipo de assinatura em C#?

Tags: c#, parâmetros, genéricos

É possível aplicar esse tipo assinatura em C#?

```
public class Teste {

    public void ver(Class<? extends Teste> tipo) {

    }
}
```

Como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mais próximo em C# da classe Class é a classe Type.

Class é uma classe genérica: `Class<T>`.

A expressão `<? extends Teste>` limita o tipo aos que herdam de Teste. O equivalente em C# é `where T : Teste`.

Assim, em C#, o "equivalente" a esse método será:

```
public void ver<T>(T objecto) where T : Teste
{
    Type tipo = typeof(T);
    //use tipo como entender
}
```

Como necessita apenas do tipo ele pode ser simplificado para

```
public void ver<T>() where T : Teste
{
    Type tipo = typeof(T);
    //use tipo como entender
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O bloco `<? extends Teste>` limita o tipo apenas às classes que herdem de **`Teste`**. Em C# se esta expressão seria `where T : Teste`. Este **`T`** pode ser qualquer coisa, ele é apenas um identificador para o tipo que será usado pelo consumidor do método.

No C# não existe nada igual à `Class<T>` do Java. Como foi notado na [resposta do ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260672/18246) o mais próximo que você pode chegar é usando `Type`.

```
public class Teste
{
    public void ver<T>(T tipo) where T : Teste
    {
        var tipo = typeof(T);
    }
}
```

Você pode ver mais sobre as *constraints* dos genéricos no C# em **[Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)**.